# Couldn't match type ‘Either String’ with ‘[]’

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this main method:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
     x <- getArgs
     case x of
         [] -> putStrLn "Empty"
         [x] ->  putStrLn (split x >>= (\(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b))
         _ -> putStrLn "More than one argument"
```

where `split` function is defined as:

```
split :: String -> Either String (String, String)
```

What am I doing here wrong? What I want to do here is just to print my tuple returned from `split` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
putStrLn (split x >>= (\(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b))
```

The monadic bind operator `>>=` has signature

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Or, in your specific case,

```
(>>=) :: Either e a -> (a -> Either e b) -> Either e b
```

So we use `>>=` when we have an `Either` and want to pass the thing inside of it to a function which itself returns an `Either`. But your function is `\(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b)`, which doesn't return an `Either`. What you want to do is take an `Either` and apply the function to the inside, leaving the `Either` part alone. That's a use of `fmap` from the `Functor` typeclass.

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
-- Specifically
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
```

So you want

```
fmap (\(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b) $ split x
```

This will return a `Either String String`. `putStrLn` is equipped to print strings. If we want to print the `Either`, then you need to use `print`.

```
print (fmap (\(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b) $ split x)
```

On the other hand, we could pattern match on the result and do something different in the `Left` case.

```
case fmap (\(a,b) -> a ++ " " ++ b) $ split x of
  Left e -> undefined -- Error case
  Right s -> putStrLn s
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about monads. I really appreaciate this precise answer!

Comment: No worries! The different types of abstraction available in Haskell can definitely look like symbol soup at first. Just remember to depend on the type system to guide you while learning, and eventually the different operations will just become second nature. Good luck! :)